# How to access span tag inside a TD using DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can I access a  inside a  element on a table and color it?

I tried using childNodes[x] but I'm not sure how to get the span.

```
<div id="myDiv">
   <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>40 (14)</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>24 (19)</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>24</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
   </table>

</div>
```

(14) should be colored in RED, 
(19) should be colored in RED

24 should be unchanged

Comment: What code do you have so far? You should post that. It's unclear what you _currently_ have a reference to, so it helps if we know what you're starting from.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("#myDiv span")` will grab the three spans. However to color part of it differently, you need to separate each span into two spans.

Answer (score 0):

Check my solution and example running: https://jsfiddle.net/tabvn/bh6y1gc3

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="myDiv">
    <table>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 <span>40 (14)</span>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 <span>24 (19)</span>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 <span>24</span>
             </td>
         </tr>
    </table>

 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("#myDiv td span");
  for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i){
    var node = nodes[i];
    var text = node.innerText;
    var openIndex = -1;
    var closeIndex = -1;
    for(var j = 0; j < text.length; ++j){
     if(text[j] === "("){
       openIndex = j;
     }
     if(text[j] === ")"){
      closeIndex = j;
     }
    }
    var str = "";
    if(openIndex > -1 && closeIndex > -1){
      for(var j = 0; j < text.length; ++j){
       if(j == openIndex){
        str += '<span style="color: red;">';
        str += text[j];  
       }else if(j == closeIndex){
        str += text[j];
        str += "</span>";
       }else{
        str += text[j];
       }

          

      }
      node.innerHTML = str;
    }
    

  }
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```